# Is it safe to use reflection and enums for logic control of MVC application access?

Tags: c#, database, asp.net-mvc-3, reflection, enums

Trying to manage access to a web site I created some necessary entities 
[image]

The goal is use a custom permission attribute for some controller's action method of my MVC application.

```
[Permissions(PermissionType.SomePermissionName, CrudType.CanDelete)]
public ActionResult SomeAction()
{
}
```

For this operation I have two enums

```
[Flags]
public enum CrudType
{
    CanCreate = 0x1,
    CanRead = 0x2,
    CanUpdate = 0x4,
    CanDelete = 0x8,
}

[Flags]
public enum PermissionType
{
   SomePermissionName = 0x1,
   //... 
}
```

Now I want the method below to check permissions

```
public static bool CanAccess(RolePermissions rp, CrudType crudType)
{
    var pInfo = rp.GetType().GetProperties();
    var res = pInfo.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == crudType.ToString());
    if(res != null)
    {
        return Convert.ToBoolean(res.GetValue(rp, null));
    }
    return false;
}
```

It works good but is it safe to use reflection here? Is it a good style? 
One more question is about such piece of code

```
var permission = PermissionService.GetByName(permissionType.ToString());
```

Here I'm trying to get a permission object from a database using some named constant from the `PermissionType` enum. 
In both cases the correct work depends on relationships between enums and some table fields or records. On other side I have a good mechanism of controlling logic (as it seems to me).
Is that a good way?

Comment: Is this is not available in ASP.NET Membership APi ?

Comment: I really don't like Membership. Besides I'd like to use my own classes, own tables, own control etc

Comment: Any reason you don't like, Other than own classes, own tables , own controls ? As I was thinking to move to Membership APi :(

Comment: Ok. The first reason [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8330340/a-way-to-avoid-deriving-from-the-provider-classes-in-mvc-authentication). The second - it's convenient for me to be able to control everything myself. Of course it's a matter of taste...

Comment: Thanks for the link , I am feeling bit better now ;)

Comment: Wow.  A well thought-out, well stated question having the proper code.  Now this is a good question.  I just wish I had a good answer for you...  Unfortunately, my Reflection fu is weak.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**ANOTHER EDIT**
In your case it would make sense to create a readonly property `ExistingPermissions` for the `RolePermissions` class, and do the merging of the four booleans into one `CrudType` within that property getter. Then you can just do `rp.ExistingPermissions.HasFlag(permissionToCheck)`.

**EDITED**

Thanks to @DevDelivery for pointing out the issue - good catch. Unfortunately the fixed solution isn't as pretty as I was hoping for, so in this case it might make sense to go with @DevDelivery's approach.

Since you have your `CrudType` as "bitfields", you can use a cleaner approach (less code and better readability):

```
public static bool CanAccess(RolePermissions rp, CrudType permissionToCheck)
{
    CrudType existingPermissions = 
                                SetPermissionFlag(CrudType.CanCreate, rp.CanCreate) |
                                SetPermissionFlag(CrudType.CanRead, rp.CanRead) | 
                                SetPermissionFlag(CrudType.CanUpdate, rp.CanUpdate) |
                                SetPermissionFlag(CrudType.CanDelete, rp.CanDelete);

    return existingPermissions.HasFlag(permissionToCheck);
}

public static CrudType SetPermissionFlag(CrudType crudType, bool permission)
{
    return (CrudType)((int)crudType * Convert.ToInt32(permission));
}
```

The drawback compared to your solution is that you will have to modify this method in case you add more operations (to the existing `CanRead`, etc.).

Comment: The problem here is that the RolePermission properties are booleans. Or'ing a bunch of booleans will just give you another boolean.

Comment: @DevDelivery - good catch, that wouldn't work indeed. Seems like the solution is not that pretty after the fix.

Answer (score 1):

Using reflection has a performance impact and the late-binding means that changing a name of a enum 
or property will not get caught by the compiler.

Plus, this code is very hard to understand, thus difficult to maintain.

Here there are only 4 options to check. A simple switch statement is easier, faster, and cleaner.

Using reflection would make sense if you were trying to allow for changes to the database or for third-party components to introduce new permissions.